# Script Error on Admin Catalog

Tags: javascript

My Magento 2 is hanging on the Catalog Page - there is an unresponsive script: lib/view/utils/dom-observer.js:201  In Firefox I can skip the script and the page loads - in Safari I cannot.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue. How I resolved was by not showing too many attributes in the product column in the admin: 
*Attributes > Advanced Attribute Properties > Add to Column Options > No*

Comment: I am getting this error in catalog detail i.e. edit page. It is not loading for me. Anyone having same issue? how to resolve?